# Is it possible to pass variable to startswith in python

Tags: python, pyqt

My question is, instead of passing String as an argument for startswith in python, is it possible to pass variable to it. Below are few line of codes mentioned.

```
self.param = self.comboBox_2.currentText()
files = [os.path.join('E:/Project/retlist', x) for x in os.listdir('E:/Project/retlist') if x.startswith(self.param)]
newest = max(files , key = os.path.getctime)
print newest
```

self.param is the variable which holds the string which i am passing to startswith function

Comment: have you tried `str.startswith(x)` ?

Comment: yeah but getting error Qstring doesnot have startswith attribute

Comment: convert your parameter to `str` and try `if "a" in x` ?

Comment: I don't think Qstring is exposed in PyQt5 are you using PyQt4?

Comment: yes I am using PyQt4

Comment: `self.param = unicode(self.comboBox_2.currentText())`.